# Why am I getting unsupportedoperation: read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am having an issue with the following syntax

```
  test_file = open("test.txt", "wb")
  test_file.write(bytes("Write me to the file\n", 'UTF-8'))
  test_file.close()
  text_file = open("test.txt","r+")
  text_in_file = test_file.read() # this is where the error emerges
  # more code goes here
```

On this syntax, I am getting

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

I got it from an online tutorial and I am using python 3. do you know what could lead to such kind of error message?

Comment: again, this might be basic yet very important when it comes to working with external files

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Read it carefully and see if you can spot the name you spelled wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. You have opened `text_file`, but the line

```
text_in_file = test_file.read()
```

wants to read from the closed `test_file`. Change the line to:

```
text_in_file = text_file.read()
```